# Negative hex literals in clojure

Tags: clojure

I found out that `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` is `18446744073709551615N` not `-1` in clojure. `(unchecked-long 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)` works, but incurs runtime costs.

Any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute the value at read time to prevent it being a runtime cost:

```
#=(unchecked-long 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest just using `unchecked-long`.

The runtime overhead is likely to be zero, since the JIT compiler should be smart enough to optimise this to a constant load.